# Is there any effect if I do not restore the application.calculation in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have turned off the

```
application.calculation = xlcalculationmanual
```

and after such a lengthy vba code I have done these at the end

```
application.calculation = xlcalculationautomatic
```

What I saw is these statement is taking 20 seconds and sometimes hanging up when I restore the xlcalculation

```
application.calculation = xlcalculationautomatic
```

I really do not understand why it is taking a lot of time for that statement. To save the time, I just neglected to restore it. Is there any effect if I do not restore it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The consequence is that no calculations will be done. So if you have a cell with formula `=A1+A2` and you change the values of A1 and A2, then the result won't be updated to the actual sum of the current values of A1 and A2 until you force a calculation manually <kbd>F9</kbd> or select automatic calculation again. This can also be done manually in Tools > Options... > Calculation.

Answer (score 0):

What I suspect is happening is that it it re-calculating the enture workbook.

Ideally, you should not disable automatic calculations because this is dangerous. (i.e. you may be looking at old cached values instead of recent values)

Instead you should verify that the problem is recalculation (i.e. manually recalculate the sheet  and see how long it takes).  If that is the problem, you should google way of speeding up calculations (i.e. splitting up your data, using static references, etc...)

Comment: On the contrary! Disabling automatic calculations is highly advisable if you want to optimize the execution of code that doesn't rely on input from worksheet formulae. It is indeed dangerous if used improperly, just like a knife (or even a spoon) is, but that's no excuse for not using utensils when you eat!

Comment: I agree with Jean-Francois. Storing the current calculation settings, changing to manual calc, running code then restoring to the prior calc setting is standard good coding.  Charles William's site has all you ever need to know - and more - on calculation, see [decision models](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsh.htm)